# QGIS2Web: Leaflet in full screen

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web

How can I make the Leaflet in full screen mode?

[image]

Comment: Coding questions on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise question is most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy.

Comment: See chapter 22 in the Procedure section of this tutorial: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

Comment: @TomazicM If a user is using Qgis2web then it's possible that the user may not be familiar with code.  The answer really has nothing to do with the resulting code.

Comment: @GreyHippo It depends. Sometimes, depending on the requirements/problem, modification of generated code is required, and sometimes, it just can be done also by code modification.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The map should fill the complete browser window? The map should initially be zoomed to the extent of the features?

Answer (score 2):

In the QGIS2Web dialog, click on the Appearance tab. A little more than halfway down click on the dropdown for Template, select Full Screen.

[image: appearance tab]

Answer (score 0):

@Llaves's answer is correct, but if you also want the map to be completely full-screen in the same way that video can be full-screen, the easiest method is to add a Leaflet plugin which does that job for you. There are three possible such plugins listed on the official Leaflet plugins page: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#fullscreen-controls.